# Exception when calling insertInManagedObjectContext:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, mogenerator

I am creating a Reddit client for iOS for learning purposes. I am using CoreData, which I set up by following the [CoreData Basics NSScreencast](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/11-core-data-basics) and I used Mogenerator to generate the model files.

I added a breakpoint to catch all exceptions and when I call the `insertInManagedObjectContext:` class method provided by Mogenerator, the app crashes on the following line:

```
return [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AZRedditAccount" inManagedObjectContext:moc_];
```

This line is in the model that Mogenerator generated (`_AZRedditAccount`). When I look at the Variables View, I noticed an odd line which I don't really understand...

[image: Odd line in the Variables View]

What do I need to do to make things work please?

**Edit:** Here is what I have in my `.xcdatamodeld` file:

[image: My .xcdatamodeld file]

**Edit 2:** I added the whole project to Github, thought it might help solve the problem: https://github.com/AzizLight/Reddit

Comment: What is in your model, did you re-run MoG after any changes, did you edit any of the generated classes, what is the crash?

Comment: MoG generated 2 classes: `_AZRedditAccount` and `AZRedditAccount`. I just added a method to `AZRedditAccount` but it never gets called since the app crashed before. If I disable the breakpoint I added, I get a `Thread 2: signal SIGABRT` error. With the breakpoint, the app crashes at the line shown in my question.

Comment: @AzizLight: You mention that you set an exception breakpoint and that's where it's stopping. So, what was the exception?

Comment: @PeterHosey I have no clue actually, that's a good question. The breakpoint is set to catch All Exceptions...

Comment: Try continuing. If the exception hasn't printed itself yet when you hit the breakpoint, it should do so after one or two continue attempts.

Comment: Here is the exception: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'AZRedditAccount''`

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of what you have in your managed object model (the .xcdatamodeld).

Comment: @PeterHosey I added a screenshot as per your request. Also, I created a new project, a Twitter client without a UI (much simpler), and I got the same exception...

Comment: That's odd. Select your .xcdatamodeld in the Project Navigator (⌘1) and pop open the File Inspector (⌘⌥1). What are its target memberships?

Comment: It's the name of the project, Reddit, and it's checked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you debug you see that your ManagedObjectContext (MOC) has no assigned PersistentStoreCoordinator (PSC) and therefore not model. In AZRedditDataModel.m you're initializing the PSC, but you're not retaining it (lines 84-109). If there's no model, the context cannot create any entities, because there's no "blueprint".